# Amazon S3 copy request timeouts

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

We're uploading files to a temporary folder in a bucket.  After that, we're trying to copy the uploaded files to its actual folder then delete the files in the temporary folder.  It doesn't timeout when working with a single file.  We're using the ThreeSharp API.

Stack Trace:

[WebException: The operation has timed out]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +5322142
   Affirma.ThreeSharp.Query.ThreeSharpQuery.GenerateAndSendHttpWebRequest(Request request) in C:\Consulting\Amazon\Amazon S3\Affirma.ThreeSharp\Affirma.ThreeSharp\Query\ThreeSharpQuery.cs:386
   Affirma.ThreeSharp.Query.ThreeSharpQuery.Invoke(Request request) in C:\Consulting\Amazon\Amazon S3\Affirma.ThreeSharp\Affirma.ThreeSharp\Query\ThreeSharpQuery.cs:479

Comment: Can you give us more information? What does the timeout look like? Are you actually making the service call, or is it timing out trying to check out a connection? Does ThreeSharp call the REST or SOAP version of the API?

Comment: Also, if you're writing a brand new piece of software, you should consider using the new AWS SDK for .NET (http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/ ), as ThreeSharp is no longer being maintained.

Comment: I tried to use the new SDK.  Nothing odd happened.  No timeout.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there's no COPY function in Amazon APIs today.

> When you want to create a copy of an
>   object in Amazon S3, today you must
>   re-upload your existing object to the
>   new name. If you do not have a copy of
>   the object, you must first download
>   the object and then re-uploaded to
>   Amazon S3, incurring data transfer
>   charges for both the download and the
>   upload as well as a GET and PUT
>   request charge.

(from http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/copy.html)

So, program library you use is doing all this job for you - it's downloading your file to your machine first, and then uploads it back to Amazon.

I suggest you to upload your file straight to it's actual folder.

Comment: The 2006-03-01 version of the S3 API (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingCopyingObjects.html) defines a `copy` operation, so there is definitely now a copy operation